# HP Proliant ML310e Gen8 with Windows 2012 lost RAID data?

Tags: raid, data-recovery

I'm having some problems where a client had a fire in the power strip feeding the UPS to their server.
When I got there the HP Proliant Gen8 server had been booted and was sitting at a setup dialog box asking which language to use. I'm guessing that something caused the server to forget it's RAID.

When I boot into Intelligent Provisioning it shows me a single Array with two 500 GB SATA drives. But, it won't boot from the RAID.

When I boot from a Linux LIVE CD I see an NTFS partition and a partition that's unrecognized on one disk and the other disk is completely a single unrecognized partition. I've not found any way to mount the NTFS partition or either unrecognized partitions.

When I boot from a Windows PE ISO CD the windows disk manager sees the HDDs and partitions but is unable to access any of them.

Can you think of any more magic I might do that let me get at their data?

Comment: Have you tried a disk in another system? How about another OS? Linux comes to mind.

Comment: Put SATA disks in separate system and Ubuntu saw the partitions but would not mount them. "Unrecognized."

Comment: Too bad. Not sure if this will help, but have you tried ntfsfix from ntfs-3g?

Comment: What can you tell us about the layout and contents of the RAID? Level, disk configuration, partitions and file systems on top of the composite, anything? It might very well allow an answer (even if that answer turns out to be "restore your most recent backup"). (Your client *does* have a solid backup regimen in place, don't they?)

Comment: 2 SATA 500 GB HDDs in a RAID0 Array. NTFS, and unrecognized partitions on HDD0; just unrecognized partition on HDD1. Windows 2012 had been running. Looking at Backup Exec backup DAT tapes now. At least 1 day lost if we must go to backup tapes, perhaps a week to the next older tape.